# Composite Component with custom behavior - PrimeFaces DataTable in full screen mode

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, liferay-6

I'm developing a custom composite component, that reuse primeface Data Table with some other features that I have in my requirements.
One of this feature is to display Table in a full screen mode. To obtain that, I develope three custom component:

***External Container***

```
    <composite:interface componentType="m3DataTable">
    <composite:attribute name="rendered" targets="idListPanel idListPanelFullScreen"/>
    <composite:attribute name="for" targets="idListPanelFullScreen" required="true"/>
    <composite:attribute name="my" targets="idListPanelFullScreen" default="left topo"/>
    <composite:attribute name="at" targets="idListPanelFullScreen" default="left topo"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <span id="#{cc.clientId}">
        <p:overlayPanel id="idListPanelFullScreen" for="#{cc.attrs.for}" appendToBody="true" dynamic="true" styleClass="m3PanelListaDatiOverlay" binding="#{cc.m3DataTableOverlayPanel}" widgetVar="#{cc.id}widgetVarOverlay" > 
        </p:overlayPanel>
        <p:panel id="idListPanel" styleClass="m3PanelListaDati" binding="#{cc.m3DataTablePanel}">
            <composite:insertChildren></composite:insertChildren>
        </p:panel>
    </span>

</composite:implementation>
```

***Header***

```
    <composite:interface componentType="m3DataTableHeader">

</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <span id="#{cc.clientId}">
                        <p:commandLink id="idFullScreen" ajax="true" actionListener="#{cc.actionListener}">
                            <p:graphicImage id="fullScreen" value="../images/empty.png" styleClass="ico_full_screen"/>
                        </p:commandLink>    
    </span>
</composite:implementation>
```

And then I have a grid component that display table inside External Component. I'm not reporting grid component code because itsn't useful forr discussion.

And finally I used component in my test page:

```
    <m3:m3DataTable id="idListCar" my="left top" at="left top" for=":ancora" rendered="#{lazyTableComponentBean.datasource.size()>0}">

        <m3:m3DataTableHeader id="listaHeader"  title="Test Table" rendered="#{lazyTableComponentBean.datasource.size()>0}">


        </m3:m3DataTableHeader>
        <m3:m3DataTableGrid id="idListaAttivitaGrid" var="car" selection="#{lazyTableComponentBean.selectedCar}"  value="#{lazyTableComponentBean.listaCars}" rowkey="#{car.name}">
         <p:column headerText="Progressivo">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.num}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Name">
```

The idea to implement full scren view mode is that clicking "idFullScreen" component link, idListPanel is reversed into OverlayPanel (idlistaFullScreen).
Inspired from this [Composite component with multiple input fields](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html) by BalusC I developed two backing component one for *m3DataTable* and another one for *m3DataTableHeader*.

M3DataTableHeader class, implements actionListener for idFullScreen:

```
    @FacesComponent("m3DataTableHeader")
public class M3DataTableHeader extends UINamingContainer{
public void actionListener(ActionEvent e){

    M3DataTable ccParent = (M3DataTable) getCompositeComponentParent(this);
    Collection<String> componentToUpdate = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(ccParent!=null){
        if(getStateHelper().get("isFullScreen")!=null && (Boolean)getStateHelper().get("isFullScreen")==true){
            ccParent.setIsFullScrenn(false);
        }
        else
            ccParent.setIsFullScrenn(true);

    }
    if(e.getComponent().getChildCount()>0 && e.getComponent().getChildren().get(0) instanceof GraphicImage){
        GraphicImage child = (GraphicImage)e.getComponent().getChildren().get(0);
        child.setStyleClass("ico_exit_full_screen");
        componentToUpdate.add(child.getId());
        componentToUpdate.add(e.getComponent().getId());
        componentToUpdate.add(ccParent.getClientId());

    }
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(componentToUpdate);
}
```

Than in m3DataTable backing component during rendering phase I copy panel children into Overlay:

```
@Override
public void encodeChildren(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
    if(getIsFullScrenn()!=null && getIsFullScrenn()){
        List<UIComponent> panelChildren = getM3DataTablePanel().getChildren();
        getM3DataTableOverlayPanel().getChildren().addAll(panelChildren);
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(getClientId());
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(getId()+"widgetVarOverlay.show()");
    }
    super.encodeChildren(context);
}
```

Plus I need that user can click on idFullScreen command link to revert view in normal mode, so during that action I can copy back overlay panel children into panel. 
Everything works fine, but after view is upadte and overlay is shown, CommandLink doesn't fire actionListener method no more.

I'm not sure that this is the best solution to impelment this beahvior, probably I miss something, any help should be useful.

I'm using PirmeFaces 3.5.23, mojarra 2.1.21 and I'm developing a portlet in Liferay 6.1.3ga3 and bridge 3.1.3ga4

Thank you for any help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Problem is due to attribute draggableColumns="true" inside grid composite component that I'haven't reported.

<p:dataTable id="idListaGrid" styleClass="m3tablePanel" draggableColumns="true"...

But I don't understand why

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

I change External Container, I removed dynamic="true" and appendToBody="true" from Overlay Panel and everything work fine

```
<composite:implementation>
<span id="#{cc.clientId}">
    <p:overlayPanel id="idListPanelFullScreen" for="#{cc.attrs.for}" styleClass="m3PanelListaDatiOverlay" binding="#{cc.m3DataTableOverlayPanel}" widgetVar="#{cc.id}widgetVarOverlay" > 
    </p:overlayPanel>
    <p:panel id="idListPanel" styleClass="m3PanelListaDati" binding="#{cc.m3DataTablePanel}">
        <composite:insertChildren></composite:insertChildren>
    </p:panel>
</span>
```